# How to show to the user the LABELS he selected instead of abstaract values?

Tags: php, arrays, forms, webforms, implode

I have the next form. I show only the most important code:

```
<form id="myform" name="theform" class="group" action="process-forma.php" method="POST">
<div class="grouphead">Favorite Music</div>
                <ol>
                    <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="favoritemusic[]" value="rock" id="rockitem" />
                        <label for="rockitem">Classical Rock from Elvis to Nirvana </label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="favoritemusic[]" value="instr" id="classicalitem" />
                        <label for="classicalitem">Instrumental, Symphonic Music</label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="favoritemusic[]" value="jazz" id="reggaetonitem" />
                        <label for="reggaetonitem">Jazz based on folk roots</label>
                    </li>
                </ol>
<button type="submit">send</button> </form>
```

On another file called “process-forma.php” for the form action, I have the next code in php:

```
<?php
    $favmusic = $_REQUEST['favoritemusic'];
    foreach ($favmusic as $key => $value) {
        echo $favmusic[$key], "<br />";
    }
?>
```

When clicking submit I can read the checked VALUES: "rock", "instr", "jazz", but what I would like to show to the user the complete phrase of the option which is described on the LABEL; so in other owrds I want to show the LABEL for these same values.

In the case of rock, the user must read: “Your favorite music is Classical Rock from Elvis to Nirvana" and not just “rock” which is not friendly (friendly for my database only) but not for the user.

Is there a way I can show the labels instead of values which many toimes use to be just abstract data like “option001”, “checkbox_002”; thta info does not mean anything for the user.

Or is it better to always REPEAT THE SAME STRING of the label in the values? Secure, effective, but is it a good workflow?

It looks that there are some answers to this but no te really, no one is related to web forms.

Comment: You can simply create an array and use it across the site. ["rock"=>"Classical Rock from Elvis to Nirvana","instr"=>"Instrumental, Symphonic Music","jazz"=>"Jazz based on folk roots,]

Comment: I am trying it. The problem is that even when no option is selected (no checkbox checked), the output is still showing me all the options. How can I output only what the user checks.